# Two filelds in model with references to the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have `Match` model and I have `Player` model.
Now I want to add to `Match` two fields like: `playerone` and `playertwo`.
I want to `playerone` have a reference to specific `Player` object and `playertwo` have a reference to another `Player` object too.

I was trying something like that:

```
rails g model Match player:references
```

but this way I am able to create only one field. And I can't create custom name for this field.

Or I can just create `playerone:integer` filed and puts here player's id (in controller). But is it ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are always going to have only 2 players per match, its fine to create player_one_id:integer and player_two_id:integer fields. In the Match model, you will just have

```
has_one :player_one, class_name: 'Player', primary_key: :player_one_id
has_one :player_two, class_name: 'Player', primary_key: :player_two_id
```

You can then just set these from a form

```
<%= f.collection_select :player_one_id, Players.all, :id, :name %>
<%= f.collection_select :player_two_id, Players.all, :id, :name %>
```

Or programatically

```
@match.player_one = Player.find(1)
@match.player_two = Player.find(2)
```

The model cmdline generator for this model would look something like this

```
rails g model Match player_one_id:integer:index player_two_id:integer:index
```